# P-Channel MOSFET - Vsd unexpectedly high when driven on?

Tags: mosfet, powermosfet

Using this cct with a FQP27P06 P-Channel MOSFET.  I am trying to switch 12V power on the high side to a non-inductive load drawing about 3A .  I am expecting 0.07 ohms x 3 A = .21V drop across the MOSFET.  Instead, the Vsd is almost 1.0V.  Is this normal?  Should I choose a different MOSFET?  Vgs is > 10V when the BJT is driven on.

I am grateful for all replies.

[image: P-Channel MOSFET Power switch cct]

Comment: The circuit looks fine, and your expectation is correct.  I would measure Vgs while the FET is on to make sure it's what you expect.  I'd also measure Id to be sure it's where you expect it to be as well.  If both of those things are right, you may have a damaged FET.

Comment: A Vgs of -10V should be plenty for 3A of conduction. Is the action of the 'digital pin' switching or steady-on? If it's PWMing, then the 1k resistors may not be allowing enough current for the MOSFET to switch on and off quickly.

Comment: Consider the DCR resistance of motor and RdsOn of FET like a voltage divider when started, then back EMF raises motor impedance with RPM. if rated load is 3A start current may be 30A thus IR= 30*0.07 = 2.1V on startup . Something is wrong. Heatsink?

Comment: Hi, you can check the GS junction using a multimeter or oscillioscope if you have, and if its reach 10V, it should be fine because current will be flowing through motor which is DS junction. And if GS is 10V but DS junction is not conducting current,mosfet is spoilt :)

Comment: Did you purchase the FQP27P06 from a franchised (manufacturer-authorized) distributor? I would expect less than 200mV drop typically.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  The ON time is hours or days, so no PWM issues.  I have measured Vgs and found it to be > 10 V.  The load is resistive, not the motor as the diagram shows.  THE FQP was purchased from a reliable supplier.  And I have tried several devices, all with the same result.  Hmmm....

Comment: What is the measured current in the load?

Comment: I have a "test" load of 3 30 Ohm resistors in parallel, so I am getting about 1.0 amperes currently.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies.  When I went from a breadboard to a soldered prototype, Vds was reduced to <= 0.09 V @ 2 Amps, considerably better than the spec.  I may have been measuring additional voltage drop associated with the breadboard contacts.  A lesson learned...